# Controlling include of js files using route in Angular

Tags: angularjs, optimization, routes

Is there any way to include **only relevant js files** for a single route, using angularjs? So not putting all includes into index.html, but call only user.js on /user route.

Something similar like calling css here [How to include view/partial specific styling in AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193492/how-to-include-view-partial-specific-styling-in-angularjs)

That way I can optimise my app to have only necessary files on each route.

Thank you,
Marko

EDIT 1) I'm using something like this [Angular controller not loading using OcLazyLoad and ngRoute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468522/angular-controller-not-loading-using-oclazyload-and-ngroute), if I have time, I will put on bitbucket later so that all can use it :D

Comment: Maybe creating a custom directive like [link](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/08/dynamically-injecting-script-tags-with-angularjs.aspx) would work.

Comment: This is looking creative :) I also ask other for people to give me their suggestions and will put best solution in edit for others to see it :) thx man

Comment: Not an answer to your question, per se, but if you optimize your js files (bundle, minify), you may find that an acceptable solution to optimizing your app.