# Making a directive load before ngController

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-controller

I am trying to get experience with angular by making an app (for my own use) and I ran into an issue.

I decided to try to implement lazy loading (like in the "Complex" part of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19434249/angular-js-how-to-load-js-files-in-partials) ) and had that working with my own additions to it.

I wanted to make components more self-contained though and decided to try to make a directive to load any javascript dependencies for me.

This left me with the following template html

```html
<div dependencies="app/components/home/controller.js" ng-controller="HomeCtrl as home">
    This is the home page.<br />
    {{home.test}}
</div>
```

When I try to load this page I see the following error

> Argument 'HomeCtrl' is not a function, got undefined

If I remove the `ng-controller` directive then my directive works fine and `controller.js` is loaded.

Based on [the source for ngController](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/bee6cbf45a91492258ecdd855fb41975d1cca44e/src/ng/directive/ngController.js#L234) I thought that setting the priority for my directive higher than 500 would work but it didnt seem to help.

I also tried moving my directives contents from `link` to `compile.pre`. It didnt help either, my directives `compile` runs before the error but `compile.pre` does not.

Is there any way to make my directive load/run first, before ngController?

Comment: Have you seen this thread - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29468522/angular-controller-not-loading-using-oclazyload-and-ngroute.  Might help.  Why not use something like 'requireJs' or '$ocLazyLoad' for your purpose?  One more thing which maybe worth a try  - remove the ng-controller and move it to the $routeProvider handler ( or state handler ) for that view?

Comment: I am just doing this for the experience; I did see that thread but it doesn't really help. I looked into those a little but the way I am using works so and it isnt too complicated. I did have the controller in the routeProvider but I wanted to simplify my routes and it seemed like controller would be better off in the relevant template anyways. I thought it would be a good introduction into making a directive then i ran into this issue.

Comment: I get your point.  Would be interesting to see a solution in your way.